# Libgdx crash on Android when opened from lock screen notification

Tags: android, libgdx, android-lifecycle

I have a bit of a rare case here which I have been trying to figure out for days and officially lost. Basically, we have OneSignal integrated in our libgdx app for push notifications, and have discovered that if the app is in the background, and the notification is tapped from the lock screen, the app fails to resume, and eventually crashes out with;

```
AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

All other scenarios work as expected;

Tap from notification drawer;

- App closed: App will open
- App background: App will foreground
- App foreground: Nothing (just some internal handling)

Tap from lock screen;

- App closed: App will open
- App background: **long wait and crash**
- App foreground: Nothing (just some internal handling)

I have identified this problem as something to do with libgdx because it happens if I initialize() a totally blank Game class in onCreate(), however if I remove libgdx completely (by setting my LAUNCHER activity to a blank Activity instead) it will successfully resume the app from the lock screen.

This happens 100% of the time on both my testing devices, one is Android 6.0 and the other is Android 8.1.

Can anyone please provide any insight to this? It seems like the activity lifecycle behaves slightly different when resumed from the lockscreen and libgdx does not take account for it?

The error above is a forced exception thrown by libgdx;

```
    void pause () {
    synchronized (synch) {
        if (!running) return;
        running = false;
        pause = true;
        while (pause) {
            try {
                // TODO: fix deadlock race condition with quick resume/pause.
                // Temporary workaround:
                // Android ANR time is 5 seconds, so wait up to 4 seconds before assuming
                // deadlock and killing process. This can easily be triggered by opening the
                // Recent Apps list and then double-tapping the Recent Apps button with
                // ~500ms between taps.
                synch.wait(4000);
                if (pause) {
                    // pause will never go false if onDrawFrame is never called by the GLThread
                    // when entering this method, we MUST enforce continuous rendering
                    Gdx.app.error(LOG_TAG, "waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing");
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                Gdx.app.log(LOG_TAG, "waiting for pause synchronization failed!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```